# check 2 fields if one has part of number change other

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I have a 2 columns under a table called tbl_data

cat_id and ip_url

Need an order to check all fields if ip_url has a number like http://0.00.00.00
then change cat_id to a certain value

i want to change only fields which starting with http://0.00 coz last 4 digits is not the same in all fields
how can i do it ?

Comment: iam doing it manual :) ,  so i asked if there is a sql command it will be easier :)

Comment: are cat_id and ip_url fields or tables? and what is your question type ? are you looking for search pattern, or really asking for a very basic SQL thing ?

Comment: cat_id and ip_url is 2 columns under a table called tbl_data

Comment: Maybe something like `UPDATE tbl_data SET cat_id = 'YourValue' WHERE ip_url LIKE '%0.00.00.00%'`.

Comment: thanks but if i want to change only fields which starting with http://0.00 coz last 4 digits is not the same in all fields

Comment: @Dr.Mezo I've posted an answer below, if you haven't already seen it. It was posted almost an hour prior to this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` to achieve this.

For example:

```
UPDATE tbl_data SET cat_id = 'something' 
WHERE ip_url LIKE 'http://0.00.%'
                               ^ anything after
```

For more information on the usage of LIKE, visit the following link:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/